# Angularjs & firebase update value

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I like firebase but they can get lazy with their docs.

To update changes in the DB is use. As per their docs

```
        var  ref= new $window.Firebase('https://mysite.firebaseio.com/arcade/'+$scope.gameID+'/scoreTracker/'+$scope.gamer+'/'+playID).limitToLast(1);;
         ref.on("value", function(data){

            $timeout(function() {
              $scope.points = data.val()

            });

         })
```

this returns

```
{"-JjFv9ICXSs17RStrk-L":{"date":1425139344646,"score":12}}
```

I simply want to get the score

without angularjs you'd use 
    data.val().score

with angularjs i've tried

```
  $scope.points = [
  $angular.fromJson(data.val())
   ]

   $scope.points = [
  $angular.fromJson(data.val().score)
  ]

   $scope.points = $angular.fromJson(data.val().score)
```

and various other variations.

Firebase's docs stops short of telling you how to get a single result

Comment: on the html side I have tried {{points.score}}

Comment: why `$angular` it should be just `angular`

Comment: either way it doesn't work

Comment: could you please create a plunkr/jsfiddle?

Comment: I believe you need to do `data.val().val().score`

Answer (score 0):

Had to do ng-repeat on the html side

{{point.score}}